# Proper Usage of the Word "Explained" in Context

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, sentence

What would be the proper utilization of the word "explained" in the following context?

1. Joe was explained that he was being charged with a crime.
   or
2. The officer explained to Joe that he was being charged with a crime.

Which option would be more appropriate or sound more formal?

Comment: #1 is wrong.  #2 is reasonably good.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why #1 is wrong and if you could please, suggest a more appropriate manner to express when someone is being explained something by another person?

Comment: Since I don't know Joe I have no idea how you'd explain him.

Comment: 'Explained' usually takes two objects, a _direct_ object and an _indirect object_. The direct object is always the thing _about which_ the explanation is given but the _indirect object_ is the person _to whom_ the explanation is given. For instance in "He explained _the controls_ to _me_" the controls needed explaining (direct object) and I heard the explanation (indirect object). The indirect object is often placed first as in "He explained to me how the controls worked" which is like your second sentence. In your first sentence Joe is treated as a _direct object_ which he is not.

Comment: Thank you @BoldBen that was a great explanation.